# Is it possible to set a User-Agent when reading a remote file using readfile() in php?

Tags: php, url, io, readfile

For example, in cURL I can use `curl_setopt($curlrequest, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'myuseragent');` in order to change the `User-Agent` when I'm requesting the page specified in `$curlrequest`.

But can I do something similar with `readfile()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can set a `user_agent` property in your `php.ini` config file or via `ini_set()` at runtime.

See http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.user-agent (via http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php)

### Update

An example (as requested)

```
ini_set('user_agent', 'RTM');
```

Comment: wait, let me get this clear, this sends this user agent every time, no matter what method of data transfer I use?

Comment: @think123 For any function or method that supports the HTTP wrapper, yes

Comment: and also, could you supply a line of code on how to do it with `ini_set` at runtime? I happened to have forgotten.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `user_agent` property in the php.ini config file, or use [ini_set](https://www.php.net/ini_set) to change it without modifying the php.ini, so you can customize on a per-script basis.

Also, one of the comments [from this page](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php) says you can do something like this:

```
<?php
    $default_opts = array(
        'http' => array(
            'user_agent' => 'Foobar',
            'header' => array(
                'X-Foo: Bar',
                'X-Bar: Baz'
            )
        )
    );
    stream_context_get_default($default_opts);
    readfile('http://www.xhaus.com/headers');
?>
```