# Why does ini_get('user_agent') doesn't work with file_get_contents() in php?

Tags: php, user-agent

I have a situation like this.

1. A crawler script fetches the content of the URL using
   `file_get_contents()`.
2. It sets the user agent as "CrawlerBot" just
   above the line where `file_get_contents()` is called using
   `ini_set('user_agent')`.

My concern is when I write `ini_get('user_agent')` in the code of URL, it gets a blank value. However when I use `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` it detects the correct user agent. Both the files are hosted on same server.

Anybody aware why does it happen?

Comment: Because that's not what ini_get does? It's for server configuration values, not request-specific values.

Comment: @EdCottrell Actually… http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696421/is-it-possible-to-set-a-user-agent-when-reading-a-remote-file-using-readfile-i

Comment: @duskwuff that's not incompatible with my comment. That question is about setting a user agent with ini_set. My comment was about trying to get the user agent making the request via ini_get. You can use ini_get to find out what user agent value, if any, is set for requests made by the server, like the one OP is making. You cannot use it to find out the user agent of a request made to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not what `ini_get()` does. It's for retrieving server configuration values (the configuration of your server), not request-specific values like the user agent sent by a requesting browser/script/whatever.

So, you can use `ini_get()` to find out what user agent value, if any, is set for requests made *by your server*, like the one you are actually making. You cannot use it to find out the user agent of a request made *to your server*.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of code to set user agent and retrive a ressource with file_get_contents.

```
//Set uri       
$uri = 'http://example.com';

//Init context
$ctx = stream_context_create(
        array(
                'http' => array(
                        'user_agent' => 'MySuperAgent/3.0'
                )
        )
);

//Try to retrieve content
if (($data = file_get_contents($uri, false, $ctx)) === false) {
        die('file_get_contents error');
}
```

ps : Note that the context array should be under http key even for https ressources.

ps2 : I strongly suggests that you set the timeout and maximum acceptable redirections on the context to avoid slowdown in your application.